# Mongoose combine two queries for same collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a query to find documents depending on another document in the same collection as below.

The first one finds the user and the second one finds the data by using that user data received. But I want to do it with one query like join in SQL

This is schema

```
var ConnectionSchema = new Schema({
socketId: {
    type: String,
    require: true
},
location: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
},
user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
date: {
    type: Date,
    require: true,
    default: new Date()
}
```

});

// queries

```
return mongoose.model("Connection").findOne({ user: userId }).populate("user").then(usr => {
    return mongoose.model("Connection").find({
        location: {
            $near: {
                $maxDistance: config.searchDistance,
                $geometry: { type: Number, coordinates: usr.location }
            }
        },
        user: { $ne: userId },
    });
});
```

Is there any way to do that with a just single query? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes there is a way you can do like this

```
    return mongoose.model("Connection").findOne({ user: userId })
.populate("user" ,
        match : {$and : [{location: {
            $near: {
                $maxDistance: config.searchDistance,
                $geometry: { type: Number, coordinates: usr.location }
            }
          }},
           {user: { $ne: userId }}]})
        .then(usr => {
        // perform your action
    });
```

Comment: It is just finding one document, is not it? I am trying to find many of them. first find the user with userId then uses the location of this user for the query.

Comment: if you will go with userID then yes ,  there will only one document because different user cannot have same userID or if have then you have to change `findOne()` to `find()` .

Comment: but in the end this query collecting users, not connections.